# Are there contexts where you would use "so much as" instead of "even"?

Tags: difference

Dictionaries say that *so much as* means the same as *even*, but I'd like to know if there are contexts where you would use *so much as* instead of *even* or the other way around? For example, is there any nuance of difference between the two in the context below.

> I managed to do a lot of things today. I **even** fixed my laptop.
>
> I managed to do a lot of things today. I **so much as** fixed my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about which dictionaries you mean, but your second example is incorrect. (The first example is fine.) M-W provides [the following definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20much%20as) of "so much as":

> : EVEN sense 1c
> // scowls if I *so much as* look at him

"Even" sense 1c has [the following definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even):

> —used as an intensive to indicate a small or minimum amount
> // didn't *even* try

Your second example doesn't indicate a small or minimum amount.

Answer (score 1):

'So much as' often implies that the speaker is expecting a particular event/action to happen, but it doesn't, and not even to a lesser degree (note that the term can be used in other ways, however this is the most common). This means that your usage of the phrase doesn't make much sense. Consider this example from [Collin's English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so-much-as):

> Laura had not reproached him, never so much as mentioned it.

The term 'so much as' fits in this context because the speaker was expecting 'Laura' to reprimand this person, however they note that she didn't even mention it in conversation. Here, 'even' can be used interchangeably with 'so much as'.

> Laura had not reproached him, she never even mentioned it.

'Even', on the other hand, has many common meanings, such as expressing that the speaker believes what precedes or follows it in the sentence is surprising. [Collin's English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/even):

> He kept calling me for years, even after he got married.

This suggests that the speaker didn't expect this person to continue calling them after he wed. This is also the definition of 'even' you used in your first example, since you did not expect that fixing your laptop would be among the list of things you did today.

So, in short, they are synonyms, but be careful when using them in place of one another, since you could make a mistake like you did in your second example by using a more common definition of 'even'.